# canvas return null onResume method

Tags: android, canvas, onresume

im trying to develop a game app.I  implement onResume and onPause methods. onPause method works fine however onResume method crushes.

```
 @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    resume();
                }
public void resume()
    {
        addAnime();
        myThread.setRunning(true);
        myThread.start();
    }
```

if im not call update in onResume method myApp works fine but if i pause game and resume it again emulator says app not responding.

if i call resume in onResume method it says canvas is null at first runnig

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        view.resume();
    }
```

I dont understand why canvas is null at the begining of the app when i call resume in onResume.Someone explain me?

**EDIT**
puase():

```
public void pause()
    {
        boolean repaet=true;
        while(repaet)
        {
            try {
                myThread.join();
                myThread.setRunning(false);
                repaet=false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        myThread=null;
    }
```

**EDIT2**
myThread

```
public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                    view.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0)
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                else
                    sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
```

**EDIT3**
here is my set runnig function

```
public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pause method:

```
public void pause()
    {
        boolean repeat = myThread != null;
        while(repeat)
        {
            try {
                myThread.setRunning(false);
                myThread.join();
                repeat=false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        myThread=null;
    }
```

myThread:

```
public class gameThread extends Thread { 
    private SurfaceView view;
    private boolean isRunning;

    private static final int FPS; // set FPS with your value

    private void sleep(long time) throws InterruptedException
    {
         Thread.sleep(time);
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running)
    {
         synchronized(this)
         {
             this.isRunning = running;
         }
    }

    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
             return this.isRunning;
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    while (isRunning()) {
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Resume method:

```
public void resume()
    {
        addAnime();
        // you must create a new thread. (You cannot use this same thread if it end)
        myThread = new gameThread(surfaceView);
        myThread.setRunning(true);
        myThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: im using class for view thats why i crate public boolean isOk=false; in main activty and i make it main.isOk=true;after the resume(); and made if(isOk)view.resume  . still i see same error. Am i missing something?

Comment: sorry fixed the error but it is still is not resping after paused and resume app. in resumue setRunning=true and in pause setRunning=false in my code.
Logcat logs like that Thread[2,tid=10408,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaf570400,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

Comment: @zeto I don't know where but in your code you have blocking the main thread and application cannot draw any views and system reports it with application not responding (This is a clue). Try to find in your code where are you calling the infinite loop or something can block the main thread. Paste onPause method maybe i find something.

Comment: @zeto Don't paste it in comment. Edit your answer.

Comment: if im not join the treat it trows thread already start error . if im not start the thread my app is not working. Im really confused

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find further information in the documentation.
[SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas())

> Start editing the pixels in the surface. The returned Canvas can be used to draw into the surface's bitmap. A null is returned if the surface **has not been created** or otherwise **cannot be edited**. You will usually need to implement **Callback.surfaceCreated** to find out when the Surface is available for use.
>   The content of the Surface is **never preserved** between unlockCanvas() and lockCanvas(), for this reason, every pixel within the Surface area must be written. The only exception to this rule is when a dirty rectangle is specified, in which case, non-dirty pixels will be preserved.
>   If you call this repeatedly when the Surface is not ready (before Callback.surfaceCreated or after Callback.surfaceDestroyed), your calls will be throttled to a slow rate in order to avoid consuming CPU.

about the use of Threads or Runneables, you can check this.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html